# Сервер томкат не хочет обрабатывать jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, tomcat

```
<%@ page contentType="plain/text; charset=UTF-8" language="java" session="false" %>
<%
    out.println("{\"RetCode\": 0, \"UserName\": \"U394_VALOTD\", \"FullName\": \"Tulaganov A.\", \"PwdA\": \"<%-- mCEvD72Z^3FV^K3 --%>\", \"PwdB\": \"<%-- 5iK*TnkT%8y9u1P --%>\"}");
%>
```

> There's a problem: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') (line 1, column 2)

Comment: Валидатор жалуется на 3 строку

Answer (score 0):

для вывода чего либо на JSP никогда не пиши код Java лучше используй JSTL так безопаснее и надежнее . ссылка  [jstl](https://metanit.com/java/javaee/3.12.php)  и  [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) 
а в твоём примере  <%= %> для вывода инф, <% %> для расчетов без вывода.